# RVM installation ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.4 Could not find gem 'rails (= 1.8.7) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I need to install ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.4 because I need to modify an old application.
(latest ruby and gems in RVM working for me fine, but I need to use this old gems and ruby)
//runing ubuntu 12.04

problem is when i try to run rake gems:install 
(and I cannot do rails new app also)

I cannot solve this and I do not have much time.
Thanks in advance for any help.

$ rvm use 1.8.7
Using /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370

$ rvm gemset use gemset234
Using ruby-1.8.7-p370 with gemset gemset234

$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.4)
actionpack (2.3.4)
activerecord (2.3.4)
activeresource (2.3.4)
activesupport (2.3.4)
bundler (1.1.5, 0.9.1)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.4)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.3)
rubygems-update (1.8.24)
rvm (1.11.3.5)

$ rake gems:install

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@gemset234/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'rails (= 1.8.7) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@gemset234/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:161:in `start'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@gemset234/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `resolve'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@gemset234/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `catch'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@gemset234/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `resolve'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@gemset234/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `resolve'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@gemset234/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@gemset234/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:27:in `specs'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:41:in `candidate?'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:60:in `setup'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p370/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p370/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@gemset234/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a drawback to the gem installation system in rails 2. If there is a dependency required for rake to run, like rails in this case, you will need to install it manually. Do gem install for each of these dependencies until rake finally runs.

Comment: Thank you, for your response. I tried `gem install rails` but still having the same error. Still Could not find gem 'rails (= 1.8.7) ruby' when I try to do rake gems:install

Comment: Gotcha, there is no Rails v. 1.8.7. Remove the offending line from `config/application.rb` / `config/environment.rb`. They probably meant Ruby 1.8.7 which should not be specified with `config.gem`.